# How to access this auto variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

i declared a test variable of auto type but now i don't know how to access it. I know how to make this prograame work without `auto` but here i want to know how to access that `auto` variable.

```
int main() {
auto test = {'1','S'};
std::cout<<test; //error no match for operator... i tried using *test or *test[0] but no solution.  
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Compiler log :

```
Compiler: mingw
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\delete.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\delete.exe"   -std=c++11   
C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\delete.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\delete.cpp:5:12: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/iostream:40:0,

                 from C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\delete.cpp:1:
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/ostream:600:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::initializer_list<char>]'

Execution terminated
```

How to print `test`?

Comment: Have you tried just `test[0]`, i.e. without the pointer dereferencing? Also, you should probably read the error message, as it usually provides some good hints.

Comment: yes! i got `no match for 'operator[]' in 'test[0]' ` error.

Comment: No match for what? Do we have to guess?

Comment: compiler log saves my time. Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error since `auto variable = { ... }` declares an `std::initializer_list`, which do not have overloaded `operator<<` for `std::ostream`. You can use, for example, range-based for to get access to values from your list.

```
int main()
{
    auto test = {'1','S'};
    for(const auto& elem: test)
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you just want the first element, you can use `std::cout << *begin(test)`

Answer (score 2):

The variable `test` is of type [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). You have to use iterators to get the values from it, or the new [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
auto test = { '1', 's' };
for (const auto& i : test)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks. next time i will look at the compiler log before posting it.